# Compare three columns and remove entire row in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have big list with data that has more than 10 columns. I need to compare three of them and display some value like "Duplicate" that I can search then and delete or delete entire row straight away. The problem is that one of the result should stay and duplicates removed.

I have tried to work through Data -> Data Tools -> Remove Duplicates but it does not remove entire row and thus output table gets messed up.

Notice! Data is not only values mentioned in example. It can be whatever in columns F, G, H

```
       F          G          H
  1  Sweden      2015       Car
  2  Sweden      2017       Car
  3  Sweden      2017       Car
  4  Sweden      2016       Bus
  5  Germany     2017       Bus
  6  Sweden      2017       Bus
  7  Germany     2015       Bus
  8  Germany     2015       Car
  9  Sweden      2017       Bus
  10 Sweden      2017       Bus
  11 Germany     2017       Bus
  12 Sweden      2017       Bus
```

Result will be:

```
       F          G          H         Q
  1  Sweden      2015       Car     
  2  Sweden      2017       Car     Duplicate
  3  Sweden      2017       Car     
  4  Sweden      2016       Bus     
  5  Germany     2017       Bus     
  6  Sweden      2017       Bus     
  7  Germany     2015       Bus     
  8  Germany     2015       Car     
  9  Sweden      2017       Bus     Duplicate
  10 Sweden      2017       Bus     Duplicate
  11 Germany     2017       Bus     Duplicate
  12 Sweden      2017       Bus     Duplicate
```

In this case either "Duplicate" will be displayed in Column Q with formula or entire rows 2,9,10,11,12 deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

putting `=IF(COUNTIFS($F$1:$F1,$F1,$G$1:$G1,$G1,$H$1:$H1,$H1)>1,"Duplicate","")` in Q1, then drag downwards should do. It test if any set of the 3 columns (F,G,H) content is repeated more than once, starting from row 1. if more than once, it put in the "Duplicate" text.